# Frozen ssh when pulling changes from remote GIT repo

Tags: git, debugging, ssh, timeout, ubuntu-12.04

I have problems with pulling changes from remote git repo, already tried bitbucket and github. I am able to clone repo and also to pull when no commits are pending to download, in case of new commits git/ssh get stuck until connection is closed by remote host, see the attachement for debug ssh output. Please give me some advices what can be the problem, or how to debug. Thanks.

Stefan

[SSH Debug output](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/67889265/git_problem.log)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally seems connected to LAN settings, after some research I tried to adjust the MTU size on ubuntu (from 1500 to 1420) and now it seems working.